# Battle Ship game Terminal Game

Tags: java

I'm new in Java and want to learn and improve.

The full project can be [inspected here](https://github.com/thadeuszlay/23_battleShip)

This is a Terminal game "Battle Ship":
The computer sets ships randomly on an ocean and you have to shoot down all those ships.

I got several questions:

1. I try to follow best practice, dependency injection, as much as possible. But I'm not sure whether my approach is a good one. For example in `OceanImpl.java`, I created classes that takes the OceanImpl-cass itself as it's parameter. Is this dependency injection implemented correctly? If not, how would you do it?
2. I tried to make the classes not larger than 100 lines, thus I exported as much as possible into separated small classses and functions, in order to be DRY, create reusable components. But for some classes I think the it's still not dry enough. For example `SetOnOceanVertically` and `SetOnOceanHorizontally` is quite similar. Is it possible to refactor them further?
3. Eventhough I used interfaces in order to make the program as flexible to changes as possible, I think it is still not flexible enough. Lookint at `Game.java`, in particular the line `int[] userInput = Helper.getIntegerUserInputInRange(ocean.getXLength(), ocean.getYLength());`, if I wanted to switch from Commandline UI to a GUI or changing from 2D to 3D, then I would have to write at least that line too. So, I can't just swap the UI and expect not to touch other parts of the code.

Main.java

```
package main;

import main.controller.Game;
import main.model.MaritimeElement;
import main.model.OceanImpl;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Ocean ocean = new OceanImpl(6, 7);

        ocean.setShipWhereThereIsPlace(MaritimeElement.AIRCRAFT_CARRIER);
        ocean.setShipWhereThereIsPlace(MaritimeElement.AIRCRAFT_CARRIER);
        ocean.setShipWhereThereIsPlace(MaritimeElement.CRUISER);
        ocean.setShipWhereThereIsPlace(MaritimeElement.CRUISER);
        ocean.setShipWhereThereIsPlace(MaritimeElement.DESTROYER);
        ocean.setShipWhereThereIsPlace(MaritimeElement.DESTROYER);

        Game game = new Game(ocean);
        game.start();
    }
}
```

OceanImpl.java

```
package main.model;

import main.controller.*;
import main.controller.assertion.AssertionMaritime;
import main.controller.assertion.AssertionMaritimeImpl;
import main.controller.utils.Helper;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class OceanImpl implements Ocean{
    MaritimeElement[][] ocean;
    Map<Point, MaritimeElement> shotsMade = new HashMap<>();
    Set<Point> shipsPlaced = new HashSet<>();
    RandomCoordinateFactory randomCoordinateFactory;
    FindFreePosition findFreePosition;
    AssertionMaritime assertShip = new AssertionMaritimeImpl();
    SetOnOcean setOnOceanHorizontally;
    SetOnOcean setOnOceanVertically;
    SetOnOcean[] setOnOcean;

    public OceanImpl(int xLength, int yLength) throws Exception {
        assertShip.isLargerThanMinimumDimension(xLength, yLength);
        ocean = Helper.initOcean(yLength, xLength);

        randomCoordinateFactory = new RandomCoordinateFactory(ocean[0].length, ocean.length);
        findFreePosition = new FindFreePosition(this, assertShip);
        setOnOceanHorizontally = new SetOnOceanHorizontally(this);
        setOnOceanVertically = new SetOnOceanVertically(this);
        setOnOcean = new SetOnOcean[]{setOnOceanHorizontally, setOnOceanVertically};
    }
    @Override
    public int getXLength() {return ocean[0].length;}
    @Override
    public int getYLength() {return ocean.length;}
    @Override
    public MaritimeElement getLocationStatusAt(int x, int y) {return ocean[y][x];}
    @Override
    public MaritimeElement shootAt(int[] userInput) throws Exception {
        int x = userInput[0], y = userInput[1];
        assertShip.isPointWithinRange(x,y, this.getXLength(), this.getYLength());
        shotsMade.put(new Point(x,y), getLocationStatusAt(x,y));
        shipsPlaced.remove(new Point(x,y));
        return getLocationStatusAt(x,y);
    }
    @Override
    public int howManyTargetsHit() {return shipsPlaced.size();}
    @Override
    public MaritimeElement getShotMade(int x, int y) {return shotsMade.get(new Point(x,y));}
    @Override
    public Result setShipWhereThereIsPlace(MaritimeElement ship) throws Exception {
        int[] position = findFreePosition.getPosition(ship.val());
        if (position[Coordinate.X.val()] != -1){
            setOnOcean[position[Coordinate.ORIENTATION.val()]]
                .setShip(position[Coordinate.X.val()],position[Coordinate.Y.val()],ship);
            return Result.SUCCESS;
        }
        return Result.FAILED;
    }
    @Override
    public void setMaritime(int x, int y, MaritimeElement ship) {
        try {
            ocean[y][x] = ship;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.getCause();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void setShipsPlaced(int x, int y) {
        shipsPlaced.add(new Point(x, y));
    }
}
```

Game.java

```
package main.controller;

import main.controller.assertion.AssertionMaritime;
import main.controller.assertion.AssertionMaritimeImpl;
import main.controller.utils.Helper;
import main.model.Ocean;
import main.model.OceanImpl;
import main.model.MaritimeElement;
import main.view.CommandLineInterface;
import main.view.UserInterface;

public class Game {
    Ocean ocean;
    UserInterface ui = new CommandLineInterface();
    AssertionMaritime assertUser = new AssertionMaritimeImpl();
    public Game(OceanImpl ocean) {
        this.ocean = ocean;
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        do {
            ui.showOceanHidden(ocean);
            int[] userInput = Helper.getIntegerUserInputInRange(ocean.getXLength(), ocean.getYLength());
            MaritimeElement shotAtElement = ocean.shootAt(userInput);
            displayResult(shotAtElement);
        } while(ocean.howManyTargetsHit() != 0);
        ui.displayFeedbackWin();
        ui.showOcean(ocean);
    }

    private void displayResult(MaritimeElement shotAtElement) {
        if (assertUser.isWater(shotAtElement)) {
            ui.displayFeedbackShotMissed();
        } else {
            ui.displayFeedbackShotHit();
        }
    }
}
```

SetOnOceanHorizontally.java

```
package main.controller;

import main.model.MaritimeElement;
import main.model.Ocean;

public class SetOnOceanHorizontally implements SetOnOcean {
    Ocean ocean;
    public SetOnOceanHorizontally(Ocean ocean) {
        this.ocean = ocean;
    }

    @Override
    public void setShip(int x, int y, MaritimeElement ship) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ship.val(); i++) {
            int xCoordinate = x + i, yCoordinate = y;
            try {
                ocean.setMaritime(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, ship);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.getCause();
            }
            ocean.setShipsPlaced(xCoordinate,yCoordinate);

        }
    }
}
```

SetOnOceanVertically.java

```
package main.controller;

import main.model.MaritimeElement;
import main.model.Ocean;

public class SetOnOceanVertically implements SetOnOcean {
    Ocean ocean;
    public SetOnOceanVertically(Ocean ocean) {
        this.ocean = ocean;
    }
    @Override
    public void setShip(int x, int y, MaritimeElement ship) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ship.val(); i++) {
            int xCoordinate = x, yCoordinate = y + i;
            try {
                ocean.setMaritime(xCoordinate,yCoordinate, ship);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.getCause();
            }
            ocean.setShipsPlaced(xCoordinate,yCoordinate);
        }

    }
}
```

RandomCoordinateFactory.java

```
package main.controller;

import java.awt.*;

public class RandomCoordinateFactory {
    private int xLength;
    private int yLength;

    public RandomCoordinateFactory(int xLength, int yLength) {
        this.xLength = xLength;
        this.yLength = yLength;
    }
    private int getRandomHorizontalXPosition(int shipLength) { return (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (xLength - shipLength));}
    private int getRandomHorizontalYPosition() {
        return (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * yLength);
    }
    private int getRandomVerticalXPosition() {
        return (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * xLength);
    }
    private int getRandomVerticalYPosition(int shipLength) {return (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (yLength - shipLength));}
    public Point getStartPointForHorizontalShip(int shipLength) {
        return new Point(getRandomHorizontalXPosition(shipLength), getRandomHorizontalYPosition());
    }
    public Point getStartPointForVerticalShip(int shipLength) {
        return new Point(getRandomVerticalXPosition(), getRandomVerticalYPosition(shipLength));
    }
}
```

FindFreePosition.java

```
package main.controller;

import main.controller.assertion.AssertionMaritime;
import main.model.MaritimeElement;
import main.model.Ocean;
import main.model.Orientation;

import java.awt.*;

public class FindFreePosition {
    Ocean ocean;
    RandomCoordinateFactory randomPoint;
    AssertionMaritime assertShip;
    public FindFreePosition(Ocean ocean, AssertionMaritime assertShip) {
        this.ocean = ocean;
        this.assertShip = assertShip;
        randomPoint = new RandomCoordinateFactory(ocean.getXLength(), ocean.getYLength());
    }

    public int[] getPosition(int shipLength) throws Exception {
        int[][] startingPoints = findFreePositionsHorizontallyAndVertically(shipLength);
        int selectRandomly = (int)(Math.random() * startingPoints.length);
        if (startingPoints[selectRandomly][0] != -1) return startingPoints[selectRandomly];

        throw new Exception("No space for ships found");
    }
    private int[][] findFreePositionsHorizontallyAndVertically(int shipLength) throws Exception {
        Point startPointHorizontalShip = randomPoint.getStartPointForHorizontalShip(shipLength);
        Point startPointVerticalShip = randomPoint.getStartPointForVerticalShip(shipLength);
        int[] coordHorizontal = findFreePositionHorizontally(shipLength, startPointHorizontalShip.x, startPointHorizontalShip.y);
        int[] coordVertical = findFreePositionVertically(shipLength, startPointVerticalShip.x, startPointVerticalShip.y);

        return new int[][]{coordHorizontal, coordVertical};
    }

    private int[] findFreePositionVertically(int shipLength, int xOffset, int yOffset) throws Exception {
        int x = xOffset,y = yOffset, k = 0, xIteration = 0;
        int[] start = {-1,-1,Orientation.VERTICAL.getValue()};

        while (x < ocean.getXLength() && xIteration < 2) {
            while (y < ocean.getYLength()) {
                MaritimeElement currentMaritimeElement = ocean.getLocationStatusAt(x,y);
                if (k == 0) start = new int[]{x, y, Orientation.VERTICAL.getValue()};
                if (assertShip.isWater(currentMaritimeElement)) k++;
                if (k == shipLength) return start;
                if (assertShip.isSpaceAvailable(currentMaritimeElement, ocean.getYLength(), shipLength, y, k)) {
                    k = 0;
                    start = new int[]{-1, -1, Orientation.VERTICAL.getValue()};
                }
                y++;
            }
            y = 0;
            k = 0;
            x++;
            if (x >= ocean.getXLength()) xIteration++;
            x = x % ocean.getXLength();
        }
        return start;
    }

    private int[] findFreePositionHorizontally(int shipLength, int xOffset, int yOffset) throws Exception {
        int x = xOffset, y = yOffset, k = 0, yIteration = 0;;
        int[] start = {-1,-1, Orientation.HORIZONTAL.getValue()};

        while (y < ocean.getYLength() && yIteration < 2) {
            while (x < ocean.getXLength()) {
                MaritimeElement currentMaritimeElement = ocean.getLocationStatusAt(x,y);
                if (k == 0) start = new int[]{x, y, Orientation.HORIZONTAL.getValue()};
                if (assertShip.isWater(currentMaritimeElement)) k++;
                if (k == shipLength) return start;
                if (assertShip.isSpaceAvailable(currentMaritimeElement, ocean.getXLength(), shipLength, x, k)) {
                    k = 0;
                    start = new int[]{-1, -1, Orientation.HORIZONTAL.getValue()};
                }
                x++;
            }
            x = 0;
            k = 0;
            y++;
            if (y >= ocean.getYLength()) yIteration++;
            y = y % ocean.getYLength();
        }
        return start;
    }
}
```

CommandLindInterface.java

```
package main.view;

import main.controller.DrawMaritime;
import main.controller.DrawMaritimeImpl;
import main.model.MaritimeElement;
import main.model.Ocean;

public class CommandLineInterface implements UserInterface{

    DrawMaritime drawMaritime = new DrawMaritimeImpl();
    @Override
    public void display(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
    @Override
    public void displayFeedbackWin() {
        display("You won!");
    }
    @Override
    public void displayFeedbackShotMissed() {
        display("Missed");
    }
    @Override
    public void displayFeedbackShotHit() {
        display("Hit");
    }
    @Override
    public void showOceanOpen(Ocean ocean) {
        genericDrawOcean(ocean, drawShipsOpenly);
    }
    @Override
    public void showOcean(Ocean ocean) {
        genericDrawOcean(ocean, drawAllShips);
    }
    @Override
    public void showOceanHidden(Ocean ocean) {
        genericDrawOcean(ocean, drawShotsMade);
    }

    private void genericDrawOcean(Ocean ocean, DrawStuffOnOcean drawStuffOnOcean) {
        for (int y = 0; y < ocean.getYLength(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < ocean.getXLength(); x++) {
                if (y == 0 && x == 0) {
                    System.out.print("\t");
                    for (int i = 0; i < ocean.getXLength(); i++) {
                        System.out.print(i + "\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                if (x == 0) System.out.print(y + "\t");
                drawStuffOnOcean.draw(ocean, y, x);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    interface DrawStuffOnOcean{
        void draw(Ocean ocean, int y, int x);
    }

    DrawStuffOnOcean drawShipsOpenly = (Ocean ocean, int y, int x) -> {
        MaritimeElement element = ocean.getLocationStatusAt(x,y);
        if(element == MaritimeElement.WATER) {
            drawMaritime.water();
        } else if (element == MaritimeElement.DESTROYER) {
            drawMaritime.destroyer();
        } else if (element == MaritimeElement.CRUISER) {
            drawMaritime.cruiser();
        } else if (element == MaritimeElement.AIRCRAFT_CARRIER) {
            drawMaritime.aircraftCarrier();
        }
    };

    DrawStuffOnOcean drawAllShips = (Ocean ocean, int y, int x) -> {
        MaritimeElement element = ocean.getLocationStatusAt(x,y);
        MaritimeElement checkForShotsMade = ocean.getShotMade(x,y);
        if (checkForShotsMade == null) {
            drawMaritime.water();
        } else {
            if(element == MaritimeElement.WATER) {
                drawMaritime.missShip();
            } else if (element == MaritimeElement.DESTROYER) {
                drawMaritime.destroyer();
            } else if (element == MaritimeElement.CRUISER) {
                drawMaritime.cruiser();
            } else if (element == MaritimeElement.AIRCRAFT_CARRIER) {
                drawMaritime.aircraftCarrier();
            }
        }
    };

    DrawStuffOnOcean drawShotsMade = (Ocean ocean, int y, int x) -> {
        MaritimeElement element;
        if (ocean.getShotMade(x,y) == null) {
            drawMaritime.water();
        } else {
            element = ocean.getShotMade(x,y);
            if(element == MaritimeElement.WATER) {
                drawMaritime.missShip();
            } else {
                drawMaritime.hitShip();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- Documentation! And a `README`.
- Try to avoid class names starting with `Set` in the future in order to avoid setter starting with `setSet` which hurt the eyes. It's not worth refactoring that.
- Some fields, like `Game.ocean`, aren't encapsulated.
- ```
  catch(Exception e) {
      e.getCause();
  }
  ```

  has no effect and most likely leads to useless `An error occured` messages at the end of the development cycle. If you don't pass on an exception, but catch it you need to handle it, throw a `RuntimeException` or inform an online service like sentry.io about it. `try-catch(Exception)` is almost never right...
- Your project has no `pom.xml`, but IDE-related files in `.idea`. I'd provide a command-line based cross-platfrom, cross-IDE build command as early as possible in order to make is as easy as possible for others to build and run your project.

Your questions:

1. I don't see dependency injection in your code. Use a FLOSS framework following Java specification for it, that's why there're there.
2. ```
   public abstract class SetOnOceanBase implements SetOnOcean {
       ...
       private final boolean horizontally; //only expose to subclasses' constructors

       @Override
       public void setShip(int x, int y, MaritimeElement ship) throws SpecificException {
           for (int i = 0; i < ship.val(); i++) {
               if(horizontal) {
                   ... x y coordinate stuff
               }else {
                   ...
               }
               ocean.setMaritime(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, ship);
               ocean.setShipsPlaced(xCoordinate,yCoordinate);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Abstracting interfaces is neat, but if you do it for anything you touch you quickly get into a YAGNI logic, especially when it comes to data containers (which roughly spoken shouldn't implement interfaces), so do it for new stuff if you can think of a use case for the interface within 5 seconds - my rule of thumb for hobby projects without technical specification and sophisticated class diagram. Later, the extraction of an interface is only one or two clicks in any modern IDE.

Comment: "Abstracting interfaces is neat, but mostly YAGNI" So you would generally at first discourage from implementing to an interface? I thought that would be best practice as it makes the code more flexible and extendable?

Comment: @thadeuszlay You're right, that was over-simplified. I proposed a rule of thumb since there's no clear border between YAGNI and having too few abstraction blocking your development.